# Installing a specific version of a package depending on group/markers/etc

Tags: python, python-poetry

We would like to install a specific version of a package with poetry depending on the environment ("production" or "preproduction").

However, we are not sure of the best way to proceed. We have identified two possibilities:

1. Put the package twice in separate groups and install only the required groups. Then, something "outside" poetry decides what groups to install. This has given problems because poetry reads all the groups to resolve the versions (and there's a duplicity).
2. Use some sort of marker, as in

   ```
   foo = [
   { version = "^2.2", markers = "python_version <= '3.4' or sys_platform == 'win32'" },
   { version = "^2.3", markers = "python_version > '3.4'" },
   ```

   but we are not sure of what environment marker would be best to use.